# how to get data from firestore database using vuexfire?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuexfire

I am writing a chat app with the following data model:[image: database image]
using the following approach:
store/index.js

```
 actions: {
bindMessages: firestoreAction(({ state, bindFirestoreRef }) => {
  // return the promise returned by `bindFirestoreRef`
  return bindFirestoreRef(
    'messages',
    db.collection('groupchats')
  );
}),
},
```

then I access the messages store.state from my vue components like this:

```
computed: {
Messages() {
  return this.$store.state.messages;
},
},
```

according to the [vuexfire docs](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/binding-subscriptions.html#binding-in-actions).
I was able to get the data of the whole collection (reactively) but I want the **messages array ** of a specific document assuming I know the document id. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
state: {
    // ...
    doc: null
},

mutations: vuexfireMutations,

getters: {
   // ...
},

actions: {
    bindDoc: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }) => {
        return bindFirestoreRef('doc', db.collection('groupchats').doc('MI3...'))
    })
}
```

---

You can make it dynamic as follows:

**Component:**

```
// ...
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('bindDoc', { id: '........' }); // Pass the desired docId, e.g. MI3...
  },
};
</script>
// ...
```

**Vuex store:**

```
state: {
    // ...
    doc: null
},

mutations: vuexfireMutations,

getters: {
  // ...
},
actions: {
    bindDoc: firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }, payload) => {
        return bindFirestoreRef('doc', db.collection('groupchats').doc(payload.id));
    }),
}
```

Comment: do I get the messages array  by just doing doc.messages?

Comment: Yes. Then you need to loop over it. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html